# Column Validation with If Formula

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula

Need your assistance in writing formula.

I have SharePoint List with a choice field Named as "Status" with "Active" and "InActive" as choices. By default this is set to Active.

What I want is, if "Queue And Metrics" are selected once it is always taking as default as Active and second time if User comes again and selects the same "Queue and Metric" then the previous entry which is stored as Active in the SP List would become InActive.

Comment: Calculated columns work in the context of current list item/row. You cannot change the value in previous list item/entry based on new entry using calculated column.

Comment: Any Suggestion How do I achieved this goal

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, if you choose "Queue And Metrics" in one column, the "Status" column shows "Active". Then if you choose "Queue And Metrics" in one column again, the "Status" column shows "InActive".

I don't think it's possible to be achieved.